# Maximum line length supported by logstash?

Tags: input, logstash, logstash-file

What is the maximum character length does logstash can read as a single event from a file (single line input, NOT multiline input)? Also does logstash take specific number of spaces/tabs in between a line as newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the [file input](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb#L137) uses [filewatch](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch), which has a [32K limit](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/blob/master/lib/filewatch/tail.rb#L181).

Answer (score 0):

The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31299540/454312) is referring to an old version of filewatch where the chunk size was [hard-coded to 32K](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/blob/v0.6.3/lib/filewatch/tail.rb#L179)

Recent file-input still uses this as the default chunk size but allows [configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-file_chunk_size) if the line is longer than 32K.

The [plugin also prints a warning](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/blob/v4.2.1/lib/filewatch/watched_file.rb#L251-L254) when a delimiter is not found reading a chunk.